# How can one set constraints to the title text such that it's size is relative to that of the superview using the Storyboard UI in "XCODE"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I need to set constraints on the title text of my application such that the font size of the text is relative to that of the superview. This would help the text to vary with the screen size.

Comment: Have you tried setting a large font size then enable `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on the UILAbel. I don't know what the storyboard name for this is as I don't use storyboards but I would imagine it has something with the words "scale" or "adjust" and "font size" in it. You would also need to have number of lines set to 1 label. Then you would pin leading and trailing to the superview. source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped, though I used another method, since I had a time limit push my application. So what I did was: 

1.) I linked and made a variable for my title text by:
@IBOutlet weak var iXyloTitle: UILabel!

2.)then what I did was, set the size of the title text relative to the superview ie: 0.031 to the size of the superview by:
 iXyloTitle.font = iXyloTitle.font.withSize(self.view.frame.height * 0.031)

Just wanted to share so that someone finding for answers may find help. Thanks a lot dude your method surely worked and made me learn another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do so.

So what I did was:

1. I linked and made a variable for my title text by:

```
@IBOutlet weak var iXyloTitle: UILabel!
```

2. then what I did was, set the size of the title text relative to the superview ie: 0.031 to the size of the superview by:

```
iXyloTitle.font = iXyloTitle.font.withSize(self.view.frame.height * 0.031)
```